# if "For Xml Path" returns a null value put a space or a period in the field instead of the null

Tags: xml, isnull

I have a line in a query
`FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2,''), '&#x0D;', ''),'&lt', ''), '&gt', '') as 'OC Comments',`

When it gets to my SSRS report, the report behaves funny if there the field is empty.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + 
opc2.commenttext
FROM mydatbase.orderedpanelcomment opc2
WHERE opc2.orderedpanelkey = opc.orderedpanelkey
AND opc2.isReportable = 1
FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2,''), '&#x0D;', ''),'&lt', ''), '&gt', '') as 
'OC Comments',
CAST(CAST(rc.resultCommentLob AS varbinary(max)) AS varchar(max)) 
'Test Comments',
CAST(CAST(lr.largeresultLOB As varbinary(max)) AS varchar(max)) AS 
'Large Result',
reqc.commenttext as 'reqcommenttext'
FROM mydatbase.requisition rq
JOIN mydatbase.result r ON r.requisitionKey=rq.requisitionKey
JOIN mydatbase.test t ON t.testKey=r.testKey
JOIN mydatbase.OrderedPanel op ON 
op.orderedPanelKey=r.orderedPanelKey AND op.isCancelled=0
JOIN mydatbase.panel p ON p.panelKey=op.panelKey AND p.isReportable=1

WHERE rq.requisitionKey=@VAR1
AND valueToReport=1
```

I know zip o about "For XML Path"  How do I tell it if this field is null to add a "period" or even better a "space" so the ssrs report does not think its empty.

If there is a way to do this inside ssrs I am open to that solution also.

I tried isnull it doesn't like that

`isnull(FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2,''), '&#x0D;', ''),'&lt', ''), '&gt', '') as 'OC Comments',`'A')`

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: I am sorry I don't know how to do all that.  I am not allowed to create tables or insert into db.  I am only allowed to query.   I have this one line is a query I was giving and it sometimes returns a null value.  I never want it to return null.  I need it to return a string such as 'Empty'  or '.'

Comment: Can you please provide SQL statement in its entirety?

Comment: REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + opc2.commenttext
 FROM mydatbase.orderedpanelcomment opc2
 WHERE opc2.orderedpanelkey = opc.orderedpanelkey
 AND opc2.isReportable = 1
 FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2,''), '&#x0D;', ''),'&lt', ''), '&gt', '') as 'OC Comments',

Comment: I put more code in the top as comment section field not big emough

Answer (score 0):

Please check a conceptual example below.

You can copy it to SSMS and run as-is (*minimal reproducible example*) to see how it works.

It creates a comma separated list of cities by using `FOR XML PATH` clause.

That technique is useful for SQL Server 2016 and earlier.

Starting from SQL Server 2017 onwards the `STRING_AGG()` function does the same in a cleaner way.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, [State] CHAR(2),   City VARCHAR(30) NULL);
INSERT INTO @tbl ([State], City) VALUES
('FL', 'Miami'),
('FL', NULL),
('FL', 'Orlando'),
('TX', 'Dallas'),
('TX', 'Houston');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT * FROM @tbl;

SELECT p.[state]
    , STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + c.City AS [text()]
        FROM @tbl AS c
        WHERE c.State = p.State
        FOR XML PATH ('')
    ),1,2,'') AS CityList
FROM @tbl AS p
GROUP BY p.State;
```

**Output**

| state | CityList |
| --- | --- |
| FL | Miami, Orlando |
| TX | Dallas, Houston |